# jquery tabletools doesn't work

Tags: jquery, websphere, jstl, datatables, tabletools

I am trying to use tabletools plugin for the datatables I already have. I have included zeroclipboard.js and also the tabletools.min.js file in my jsp page. I have created a folder swf under WEB-INF and added the copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf file in that directory. I am using

`<c:url var="copy_csv_xls_pdf" context="${renderRequest.contextPath }" value= "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" />` to get the path

I have included the path as

```
"oTableTools": {
   "sSwfPath": "<c:out value="${copy_csv_xls_pdf}" />"
}
```

I don't get any errors when I look at firebug but still all the options are disabled except the print option. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about using the EL expression directly ?

```
<c:set var="copy_csv_xls_pdf" value="/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"/>

"sSwfPath": "${copy_csv_xls_pdf}"
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get error: GET `http://localhost:10039/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I am wondering if there is any version conflict, this is what I have: `File:        jquery.dataTables.min.js
 * Version:     1.9.0 and   File:        TableTools.min.js
 * Version:     2.0.2`

Comment: `http://localhost:10039/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf` ? aren't you missing the web app name ? like `http://localhost:10039/MyWebApp/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf` ?

Comment: I am using websphere portal server, i think it works different than regular tomcat server, where we can directly get the url. The url for portal server is all encrypted. The way I have accessed images under web-inf is using `<c:url />`.